# Best way to customize Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, customization, spree

I need to modify Spree (functionality and views). But Spree installs as a gem (it's not simple application), I believe it's actually a Rails engine right? I'm pretty new at all of this.

But what is exactly the best way to grab Spree and customize it entirely to create your own ecommerce solution?

Thank you.

PS: Using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily customize spree by overrides. When you generate a fresh spree site inside your Rails app, you can see it creates empty directories like views, controllers etc. When your app is loaded, it first looks at this location and then loads from Gem. Assume you want to customize product display page, place show.html.erb into app/views/products/ and customize it the way you want.

Comment: What I did was look in the spree_core gem to see which files were being loaded (i.e what the partials are called)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer:

http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/customization.html